オープンソースでGit LFSが設定されている場合の対処方法
学習のために
https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master
をDownload Zipでダウンロードしました。
その後、ためしにgit pushを上記とは別のリポジトリにgit pushしようとすると下記のエラーがでました。（もともとあった .gitフォルダを消して、別のリポジトリを向くように git initからはじめてgit pushしています）

どうやら Git LFSが使われている場合に自分のマシーンでGit LFSの設定が有効になっていないと、エラーになるようです。（調べたところ上記でYesを押すと、Git LFSの設定が始まってしまうようなので、よくわからないので、Noを選びました）
調べたところ.gitattributes がGit LFSの設定ファイルなので、おそらくこの .gitattributesファイルを削除してしまえばエラー消えると推測しています（まだ試していません）。
結局どのように設定するのが正解なのでしょうか？
Git LFSというと管理しているリポジトリとは別に大きなファイル用のサーバーを用意しないといけないと思うのですが
https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master
には、その大きなサーバーがどこにあるのか（URLらしきもの）が見当たりません。
ちなみに.gitattributesファイルの中身は下記でした。
https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master/blob/main/.gitattributes
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
assets/audio/ filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

一方で、wavファイルはassets/audioフォルダの中にすでにあるように見えます。
https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master/tree/main/assets/audio

質問：
オープンソースのファイルがGit LFSで扱われている場合どのようにすればよいのでしょうか？

私がどのようにしたいかに依存しそうですが Git LFS をそもそも使ったことがないので、対処方法がすべて推測になってしまいます。というか https://github.com/ufrshubham/ski_master がどういう状況にあるのか、わかっていないので、対処するもなにも、どういう状況なのか知りたいです（判別方法は .gitattributesファイル を見るであっている？）

エラーを消すだけなら、.gitattributesファイルを削除？
自分でも大きなファイル用のサーバーを用意したい場合はどうやって設定する？

そもそもオープンソースなので、どこかに大きなファイル用のサーバーがあってそこから勝手にダウンロードされるのでは？

本プロジェクトは、そんなサーバーはなく、assets/audioフォルダに直置きされている？？








追記：実際にFlutterを動かしたときはAudio系のエラーが出たので、Audio使用箇所を全てコメントアウトしてから、実行して動かしました。

参考: 大きなファイルを管理する - GitHub Docs

ZIP で落としたリポジトリデータの中にある assets/audio 以下の wav ファイルは実際のサイズとは一致しておらず、Git LFS を有効にした状態で pull しないと中身を確認できないかと思います。最終的に何がしたいのかをはっきりさせた方がよいかと。

@cubick 実際に動かしたところ audio系のエラーがでたので、ソースコードからaudio系のコードは片っ端にコメントアウトして動かしました。実際のサイズは違っていたんですね。うーん。確かに何がしたいかはっきりさせたほうがいいですね。とはいえ、学習なんで、一旦動けばなんでもいい（音がなくてもOK）。いや学習だからこそ音もGit LFSも知っておいたほうがいいと、現段階ですぐに方向性を決めかねています（本サイトのガイドラインとずれそうですが、質問段階ではどういう状況なのか判断できておらず...）

オープンソースでGit LFSが設定されている場合の対処方法 のコメントを受けて色々試してみたところ。過去にgit lfsをインストールしていたので（そのときは挫折）、Download Zipではなく git clone したら音自体鳴りました。
大きなファイル用のサーバー情報はどうやらコミット自体に埋め込まれているようです（埋め込まれているようだということしかわからず、具体的にどこのサーバーなのか確認する方法自体はわからず）。
このまま別のリポジトリに git push してしまっていいのかどうかお作法的にわからず、別のリポジトリに git pushは試していません。
